Replacing value coming from JSON in pandas dataframe cell
I am trying to replace a value in a pandas dataframe cell that I am constructing from a JSON file that I get from Airtable API the JSON file looks like this one:
[
    {
        "id": "rec0Y7ydscZnU5NjZ",
        "createdTime": "2023-03-17T16:32:57.000Z",
        "fields": {
            "field_id": [
                "recq6vsFWI2H8j84i"
            ],
            "field_name": "S-166",
            "currency": [
                "Dolares"
            ],
            "state": [
                5
            ],
            "roi": {
                "specialValue": "Infinity"
            },
            "investment_return": {
                "specialValue": "NaN"
            },
            "value_amount": 16559.51178956216,
            "income": [
                31978.5
            ]
        }       
    }
]

Obviously this is a sample and I am replacing the real keys and some values, because they are from a private application, but what I am trying to do once I get the API response and then convert the JSON into a dataframe using the code below, is to replace the values {"specialValue": "Infinity"} from roi key and {"specialValue": "NaN"} from investment_return key with zeros:
#read_json.py
def read_json():
    # Open the JSON file
    with open('json_test.json', 'r') as file:
    # Parse the JSON data
        data = json.load(file)

        # Extract all fields from the "fields" dictionary and create a DataFrame
        df1 = pd.DataFrame([record['id'] for record in data],columns=['id'])
        df2 = pd.DataFrame([record['fields'] for record in data])
        
        df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
        
    return df

Then once I have the JSON data converted into a dataframe I am trying to replace the values using this code:
df.replace('{"specialValue": "Infinity"}', np.nan, inplace=True)

For some reason is not working:
Here I am using the read_json() function I described above to generate the dataframe from the JSON file gotten from API response, and inspecting the resulting dataframe:
df = read_json()
print(df)

                  id             field_id field_name   currency state  \
0  rec0Y7ydscZnU5NjZ  [recq6vsFWI2H8j84i]      S-166  [Dolares]   [5]   

                            roi        investment_return  value_amount  \
0  {'specialValue': 'Infinity'}  {'specialValue': 'NaN'}   16559.51179   

      income  
0  [31978.5] 

Then once I want to replace() for example the string {"specialValue": "Infinity"} by NaN with numpy:
# replace string value with NaN
df.replace('{"specialValue": "Infinity"}', np.nan, inplace=True)
print(df)

what I would expect is to get for the column roi an nan value, but I am still getting the same string that I receive from the API:
0  rec0Y7ydscZnU5NjZ  [recq6vsFWI2H8j84i]      S-166  [Dolares]   [5]   

                            roi        investment_return  value_amount  \
0  {'specialValue': 'Infinity'}  {'specialValue': 'NaN'}   16559.51179   

      income  
0  [31978.5]  

Can somebody give me a possible approach on how to convert those into NaN or zeros?

Why not change the values in the dictionary before constructing the DataFrame?

That's a good idea, any suggestion on how to do it?

Easier to change the values in the dictionary before constructing the DataFrame.
For example:
import json

data = '''
[
    {
        "id": "rec0Y7ydscZnU5NjZ",
        "createdTime": "2023-03-17T16:32:57.000Z",
        "fields": {
            "field_id": [
                "recq6vsFWI2H8j84i"
            ],
            "field_name": "S-166",
            "currency": [
                "Dolares"
            ],
            "state": [
                5
            ],
            "roi": {
                "specialValue": "Infinity"
            },
            "investment_return": {
                "specialValue": "NaN"
            },
            "value_amount": 16559.51178956216,
            "income": [
                31978.5
            ]
        }       
    }
]
'''

for datum in json.loads(data):
    fields = datum.get("fields", {})
    for k in "roi", "investment_return":
        dk = fields.get(k, {})
        if dk.get("specialValue") in {"Infinity", "NaN"}:
            dk["specialValue"] = 0
    print(json.dumps(datum, indent=2))

Output:
{
  "id": "rec0Y7ydscZnU5NjZ",
  "createdTime": "2023-03-17T16:32:57.000Z",
  "fields": {
    "field_id": [
      "recq6vsFWI2H8j84i"
    ],
    "field_name": "S-166",
    "currency": [
      "Dolares"
    ],
    "state": [
      5
    ],
    "roi": {
      "specialValue": 0
    },
    "investment_return": {
      "specialValue": 0
    },
    "value_amount": 16559.51178956216,
    "income": [
      31978.5
    ]
  }
}


After parsing your JSON, you no longer have strings, but objects.
In particular, you can check that:
type(df.at[0, 'investment_return'])
# dict

You could take advantage of the mutability of dictionaries and of the map method (applymap before pandas 2.1):
def replace_in_dict(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict) and 'specialValue' in x and x['specialValue'] == 'Infinity':
        x['specialValue'] = 'NaN'

df.map(replace_in_dict)

print(df)

Modified df:
                  id             field_id field_name   currency state                      roi        investment_return  value_amount     income
0  rec0Y7ydscZnU5NjZ  [recq6vsFWI2H8j84i]      S-166  [Dolares]   [5]  {'specialValue': 'NaN'}  {'specialValue': 'NaN'}   16559.51179  [31978.5]


Thanks for your inputs @mozway, what I really want to replace is not the value 'Infinity' in the key: value pair by 'NaN', but replace the whole srtring {"specialValue": "Infinity"} and also the other one {"specialValue": "NaN"} which corresponds to the key: value in the JSON by a nan in the dataframe generated.

@superunknown you can still use the same logic. If you have a dictionary and it has a single key, etc. then replace with NaN. (Note that it's not what you show in your output)

Hi thanks @SIGHUP for the provided solutions, I could add some stuff to your chuck of code and ended with an approach that finally replaced the dicts in the JSON keys by zeros.
